# Prevent input date changed by browser after submission (ransack query against created_at)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have this ransack form with input box of created_at for user to search for entries created in certain date range:

```
= search_form_for @q, url: entries_path do |f|
    = f.label :created_at_gt, 'Date range'
    = f.text_field :created_at_gt
    = f.text_field :created_at_lt
```

Everything works fine but after submission the input date fields are changed by browser, for example, from the original input date `2013/08/23` to `2013/08/23 12:00AM`. Is it possible to prevent browser from changing these date inputs?